# In terms of the queries we write, what would be the difference between the queries that we write in sql and spark sql?

Tags: sql, apache-spark

We have a python scripts that parses the sql script (select, insert) to get the source and target columns while inserting data from one table to another. Right now we parse only SQL queries. Now when we want some Spark SQL queries to be parsed using the same model, will the structure of the queries change from SQL to Spark SQL?

Comment: How would a sample insert/select/update query written in Spark SQL look like?

Comment: Spark SQL actually uses Hive's engine for queries so it's same as HQL. I don't think it will be a problem if your script just parses only columns.

Comment: ANSI or ORACLE SQL?

Comment: ORACLE SQL is what I am looking to query through Spark SQL